# Plotly Dash : Access dcc.Store components without a callback

Tags: python, callback, plotly, plotly-dash

For my multi-tab application, I am working on a snapshot / PDF print feature of a App view.

In the file that generates the PDF, I'd like to access components store in `dcc.Store` from other `tab.py` files.

```
index.py

app.layout = html.Div([

    # header
    html.Div([

        # Store component for tab1.py
        dcc.Store(id="store1", storage_type="local"),

        # Store component for tab2.py
        dcc.Store(id="store2", storage_type="local"),

        ],
 
    )

])
```

The pdf generate file returns pdf layout/design, I'd like to access components from `dcc.Store`, something like below.

```
def report(store1, store2):

    return html.Div(

                    html.H2("Effective Lease Calculations"),

                    # Access dcc.Store component
                    print_value = store1['val']

                    html.Div(
                        print_value,
                        style={
                            'marginTop': '2in',
                            'fontSize': '28px'
                        }
                    ),

 )
```

My question is, can you access `dcc.Store` components store locally without using `State("store1", "data")`in callback?

Answer (score 1):

Accessing anything in the `dcc.Store` component must be done, ultimately, with a callback. You can set the `dcc.Store` as either a `State` or `Input` to your callback, and you can pass the store, or values in it, along to other functions.

The only exception being if you are using it as an `Output`. In that case, you could set values, but it would overwrite anything already in the `dcc.Store`. To avoid that, you're back to taking it in as an input or state and updating the existing values.